# Heroku - error DNS

Tags: dns

Amigos, ¿cómo andan?
Me aparece el siguiente error, ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar? (No funciona mi página tampoco --> [www.espaciosliquidos.com.ar](http://www.espaciosliquidos.com.ar)).
La plataforma no la desarrollé yo, sino que lo hicimos a través de un proveedor pero no tenemos contratado un servicio de soporte. Entiendo que por el error que nos arroja, es por un tema del DNS. Hace poco menos de un mes, nuestro proveedor lo que hizo fue realizar un upgrade de Heruku para que podamos tener el certificado SSL. Perdón si no soy muy claro, pero es lo que logro entender el error que veo. Es dificil de entrar al tablero de dev y modificar algo o podría romperlo? Tampoco me estan funcionando los correos electrónicos que los tenemos a través de Ferozo (https://ferozo.email/).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822